# Social login with Jhipster Uaa service and gateway

Tags: spring-boot, angular5, jhipster, spring-social

i have set request from gateway to uaa to do social login it's work, and it's open the facebook page, but when redirect here appear the  problem, which  you will redirect to ? to gateway or Uaa ?
 message that appear https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSWpI.png

Comment: Have you looked in browser debug tools at the redirection URL?

Comment: i not found redirection url in Network inspect